# Read millisecond tick data without decimal point format to zoo series

Tags: r, indexing, zoo, financial, milliseconds

I'm trying to read some CSV-format financial tick data (source: [HISTDATA_COM_ASCII_EURUSD_T_201209.zip](http://www.histdata.com/download-free-forex-historical-data/?/ascii/tick-data-quotes/eurusd/2012/9)) into a zoo series. The data is indexed by a time column which contains timestamps formatted such as `20120902 170010767` - almost like `%Y%m%d %H%M%OS3` except milliseconds are not seperated by a decimal point as required by `%OS3`.

I have attempted to force the required decimal point by dividing the latter (right) half of the timestamp by 1000 and pasting back together again:

```
FUN <- function(i, format)  {
    sapply(strsplit(i, " "), function(j) strptime(paste(j[1], as.numeric(j[2])/1000), format = format))
}
read.zoo(file, format = "%Y%m%d %H%M%OS3", FUN = FUN, sep = ",")
```

However, this has not worked - could someone please shed some light on how best to do this properly?

Many thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could obviously make this shorter but this gives the idea well:

```
> tm <- "20120902 170010767"    
> gsub("(^........\\s......)(.+$)", "\\1.\\2", tm)
[1] "20120902 170010.767"
> strptime( gsub("(^........\\s......)(.+$)", "\\1.\\2", tm), "%Y%m%d %H%M%OS")
[1] "2012-09-02 17:00:10.767"
```

Comment: Beat me to the punch! Here's one shorter expression: `gsub("(\\d{3}$)", ".\\1",  tm)`

Comment: I wasn't sure that he would be getting all of the cases with three characters in the 'millisecond' columns, or I might have used a similar "(...$)" (just as few characters and not as many pesky shift keys.)

Comment: Awesome, DWin - works great. But what's the risk with using `gsub("(\\d{3}$)", ".\\1", tm)`?

Comment: I was not sure that your trailing decimal digits would all be in the right place so I decided to use the space between the date and time as the "hinge point" rather than the end of each character element.

Comment: Thanks. Finally, why `%OS` rather than `%OS3`?

Comment: Because that's what worked on my OS. Each OS is different in how it handles the milliseconds spec and mine wasn't working properly with "%OS3", yours on the other hand might work well with it. Notice that the `strptime` help page documents using "OSn" for output and only mentions using "OS" with `strptime`.